# Cannot align a table inside a Wordpress widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have just set up a simple login form in a footer widget on a Wordpress site. I was delighted to get the form working (yay!) but I simply cannot get the elements in it aligned left.

http://decentdesign.co.uk/jojusolar/

The code for the form itself is:

```
<form id="loginForm" target="_top" action="https://jojusolar.pvmeter.com/solar/j_spring_security_check"> 
 <table id="loginFields"> 
 <tr> 
 <td align="left"><span id="usernameLabel">Login</span> 
 </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="left"><input class="field" type="text" name="j_username"/></td> 
 </tr> 

 <tr> 
 <td align="left"><span id="passwordLabel">Password</span> 
 </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td align="left"><input class="field" type="password" name="j_password"/></td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 

 <td align="left"><input type="submit" value="Connect"/></td> 
 </tr> 
 </table> 
 </form> 
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://jojusolar.pvmeter.com/solar/solarwidgetlostPassword.jsp', '', config='height=280, width=280, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');">Lost password?</a>
```

Any ideas how I can get all the elements aligned left? Should be simple enough surely... No idea why I am finding it so hard.

Sorry if I have done something to make the code gods angry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have the following rule in your stylesheet:

```
table td { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Thanks. As suspected I am being a cretin.

Answer (score 0):

in used theme  css below code is there.

```
table td {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;}
```

so you can over-write the css code using parent class or id  like.. then Your problem is solved.

```
#loginFields td {
    text-align: left;
}
```